# Limit of sequence partially applied to a function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, $(c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ and $(d_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be real-valued sequences and $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ monotone with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. We also know about $a_n$ and $c_n$ that they tend to infinity. Do we then have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_nb_n}{c_nd_n}=1 \Leftrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(a_n)b_n}{f(c_n)d_n}=1?$$

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_n =n ,b_n =n , c_n =n^2 , d_n =1$, $f(x) =\ln x$ then we have $$\frac{f(a_n ) b_n }{f(c_n ) d_n } =\frac{n\ln n}{2\ln n} =\frac{n}{2}\to \infty$$